# "Swift Core Data" How to add a Scope Bars to UISearchBar?

Tags: swift, core-data, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchcontroller

So, I have a `tableView` with `NSFetchedResultsController`! I have also a `UISearchController`, and works perfectly! But I need a Scope Bars to the `UISearchBar`. How to create and how to add a Scope Bars in Swift Core Data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the search bar `scopeButtonTitles` at the time you obtain it from the UISearchController. As you present the search controller, set the search results controller as the search bar's delegate, so it will get `searchBar:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:` when the user changes scope buttons, and there you just call `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` and deal with the search as you're already doing — taking account, now, of what the current scope button index is.

Comment: Can you help me by code? Thanks

Comment: Because I'm a new to the Swift!

Comment: This video explains you how to do it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZ_S2GHFwW4